# Custom node template based on field condition

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

Is it possible at all to create a node template file based on a specific field value?

For example I already have a node template file called "**node--video.tpl.php**" for nodes of content type **video**. I would now like to add a **checkbox field** in that content type.

If the box is unchecked then it will use the above template.

If the box is checked then it will use a different template.

**UPDATE**: I added the following to my template file as Mohammed suggested, but I am not getting the changes.

```
function motg_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

$node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->field_solo[0]['value'] == 1)
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__solo';
  } else
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__video';
  }
}
```

My field "field_solo" is correctly outputting a value of 0 or 1 also.

Comment: what is the template file name you used? and did you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes the cache is cleared. Template name: node--solo.tpl.php and node--video.tpl.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I had to add "[und]" to the if statement:

```
$node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->field_solo['und'][0]['value'] == 1)
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__solo';
  } else
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__video';
  }


}
```

Comment: goo you got it :-)

Comment: @Dan I think there is a typo error. Its should be theme_hook_suggestions instead of theme_hook_suggestion

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do that in the preprocess node function something like this:

```php
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  if($node->field_solo[0]['value'] == 1)
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__theme1';
  } else
  {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__theme2';
  }

}
```

Here if the condition is true then the node template would be `node--theme1.tpl.php`

and if the condition is false then the tpl would be `node--theme2.tpl.php`.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. Could you please add to your example above the condition of: if a field named 'field_solo' has a value of 1.

Comment: what is the type of the field is it just a check box?

Comment: any way I have updated the code do let me know if that works

Comment: I'm getting a server error with that Mohammed. I have a check box field of type Boolean (on or off). Any ideas?

Comment: could you post the error in the question.

Comment: I found out that it is because I already have in my template "THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables)". Can I place your code into this one? Or how can they play nice together?

Comment: yes you can place it with in that function

Comment: Hmmm...No more error message, but the if/then statement is not using the suggested theme files. I've updated my question. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: it should be variables and not vars since the variable passed is variables, you should use the same variable passed to the funtion

Comment: have made a small edit to my answer. add a squre bracket can you check that.

Comment: No, that didn't change anything. Cleared cache also.